# How to count the # of correctly selected models by a feature selection method in its output structured as a list or df in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, count, regression, benchmarking

I have ran several optimal variable/model selection methods from machine/statistical learning on the same file folder of 58,000 (csv formatted) randomly generated synthetic datasets (all of the same size) in order to compare which method correctly selects the true underlying model for each dataset the most times. All of the scripts & many of the datasets can be found in my [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/Spencermstarr/Estimated-Exhaustive-Regression-Project) for this research project.

I have already gotten the output/results I need, each of the file formatted datasets' names are formatted in the following manner: n1-n2-n3-n4 where n1 begins at 0 and ends at 1, n2 begins at 3 and ends at 15, n3 begins with 1 and ends with 9, and n4 begins with 1 and ends with 500.The dataframe/list with the results looks like the following:

```
> str(BM1_models)
'data.frame':   58000 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ V1: chr  "0-3-1-1;  X1, X2, X3" "0-3-1-2;  X1, X2, X3" "0-3-1-3;  X1, X2, X3" "0-3-1-`4;  X1, X2, X3" ...`

> head(BM1_models, n = 4)
                    V1
1 0-3-1-1;  X1, X2, X3
2 0-3-1-2;  X1, X2, X3
3 0-3-1-3;  X1, X2, X3
4 0-3-1-4;  X1, X2, X3

> tail(BM1_models, n = 4)
                                                           V1
57997         1-15-9-497;  X2, X3, X4, X9, X10, X11, X13, X14
57998 1-15-9-498;  X2, X3, X5, X6, X8, X9, X10, X11, X12, X15
57999     1-15-9-499;  X3, X4, X5, X6, X8, X10, X11, X12, X15
58000               1-15-9-500;  X2, X4, X6, X7, X8, X10, X11
```

How to tell whether the ML variable/factor selection method (in this case LASSO) is right for any given dataset is if the n2 for that dataset says 3, then the Independent Variables selected should be X1, X2, X3, if it says 4, the underlying structural model is X1, X2, X3, X4, and so on up until 15 (I'll explain what n1, n3, & n4 signify in a p.s. section at the bottom). So, I need to write something like a count function within a complex if function inside of it all within an lapply function here, but I don't know how exactly.

p.s. Part1
The datasets & scripts are also available in this [GitHub repository](https://github.com/Spencermstarr/EER-Research-Project) of mine which should be far easier to navigate than the first one I linked to.

p.s. Part2
To clarify, if n2 = 5 for a given dataset and the model chosen was X1, X2, X4, X5 (known as an omitted variable model  or X1, X2, X3, X4, X5, X8, X9, etc. (known as an extraneous variable model), it is not correct. Only a model which includes all of the variables X1 through Xn2 should be counted, every other result should not be.

p.s. Part3
n1 indicates the amount of multicollinearity between factors in the true (underlying) structural regression equation, n3 indicates the error variance, and n4 indicates which of the 500 random variations out of all possible randomly generated datasets for each set of the other 3 parameters it is (this is a Monte Carlo Simulation).

Answer (score 1):

If I get this right, the idea is to check if the second part of a string of the form `'X1, X2, ..., Xn'` equals what should be expected based on the first part of that same string. I think the easiest way is to write a function that makes the comparison for any single string, then `sapply` it over the string vector:

```r
# testing df, only first (good) and last (bad) entry
df = data.frame(V1 = c('0-3-1-1; X1, X2, X3', '1-15-9-500; X2, X4, X6, X7, X8, X10, X11'))

good_model = function (str) {
  str  = unlist(strsplit(str, '; '))
  desc = str[1]
  pred = str[2]
  n_2  = unlist(strsplit(desc, '-'))[2]
  expt = paste0('X', 1:as.integer(n_2), collapse = ', ')
  identical(pred, expt)
}

df$good = sapply(df$V1, good_model)

df
#                                       V1  good
#                      0-3-1-1; X1, X2, X3  TRUE
# 1-15-9-500; X2, X4, X6, X7, X8, X10, X11 FALSE
```

Note: I assumed the character after `;` in the original string was a space, if it is a `<tab>` then the first call to `strsplit()` should be updated.

Comment: It is indeed a space, I added it in just to make it look more distinctly separated between the dataset name and the variables selected for that dataset.

Comment: The answer you provided looks promising, like something I can work with just by counting up the Trues or converting them to 1s, then summing them, but is there a simple way do set the dm object you specified so that it includes all 58k elements instead? That would do the trick! I tried to do it myself using an lapply, but then realized that it wouldn't work because each i in the lapply function would only be one string, so I couldn't use the standard c('') in the usual way. Perhaps this could be done via an append, but I think I would have to do the first element separately then.

Comment: @Spencer, if `df$V1` has 58k elements then `df$good` will also end up having 58k elements. You can get the number of 'good' models doing `with(df, sum(good))` or the 'success rate' by `with(df, mean(good))`.

Comment: okay, I am considering using this answer as the backbone of a follow up question at this point because I seem to be missing something or maybe 2 or 3 things crucial here because this is what I am getting.
> with(df, sum(good))
[1] 1
> with(df, mean(good))
[1] 0.5

Comment: One more thing I should add as a detail since you asked me about it in your answer, I actually inserted two spaces after each ; not just one, so I just went back and added two spaces in the str = line of the good_model function, so,   str  = unlist(strsplit(str, ';  ')) which I thought might be the quick fix, but it seems to have made matters worse because now I am getting
> with(df, sum(good))
[1] 0
> with(df, mean(good))
[1] 0

Comment: @Spencer, the output is ok for the minimal data frame I made up, there are 2 entries, one good and one bad, so a .5 success rate. I think this conversation might be getting a bit outside SO focus, If you can point me to the relevant file in your repo I would be happy to help. I'am opening an issue in github now.

Comment: Sorry for the massive delay, I ended up panicking and trying to do the counting in Excel instead because I figured I could do it 'manually' there so to speak, but that ended up being a huge waste of time!

The two files in my aforementioned GitHub repository for this project (https://github.com/Spencermstarr/EER-Research-Project) are called 'IVs_Selected_by_LASSO' (a csv file) and 'Quantifying LASSO's performance' (an R script file).

Comment: Hey @Spencer, I issued a pull request for you at github with this code the day you posted your last comment on this... please take a look at it